# Nested selectsors in Angular form

Tags: angularjs, for-loop

There is a simple form with 3 drop-down selectors and I have an object with predefined data with values for this selectors. This data is nesting up to 5 root and this is simplified example.

How to get a list with engines in the 3rd drop-down after choosing of the automaker and model of the car. **Volkswagen >> Golf >> 1.6 L**

http://jsfiddle.net/tkkonk78/

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="AutoCtrl">
<select ng-model="selected.auto"
        ng-options="a.automaker for a in data">
    <option value="">-- Automaker --</option>
</select>
<select ng-model="selected.models"
        ng-options="b.name for b in selected.auto.models">
    <option value="">-- Model --</option>
</select>
<select ng-model="selected.engines"
        ng-options="???">
    <option value="">-- Model --</option>
</select>
```

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [] );

myApp.controller('AutoCtrl',
['$scope', '$location', function ( $scope, $location ) {

$scope.selected = {};

$scope.data = [
     { 
        "id" : "1",
        "automaker" : "Volkswagen",
        "models": [
            { "name": "Golf",
              "engine": ["1.0 L", "1.6 L", "2.0 L"]},
            { "name": "Passat",
              "engine": ["1.8 L", "2.6 L", "3.0 L"]},
            { "name": "Polo",
              "engine": ["0.8 L", "1.0 L", "1.4 L"]}
        ]
    },{
        "id" : "2",
        "automaker" : "Toyota",
        "models": [
            { "name": "Venza",
              "engine": ["1.2 L", "1.6 L", "2.0 L"]},
            { "name": "Corolla",
              "engine": ["1.8 L", "2.6 L", "3.0 L"]},
            { "name": "Yaris",
              "engine": ["0.6 L", "1.0 L", "1.4 L"]}
            }
        ]
    }
  ]
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<select ng-model="selected.engines"
        ng-options="c for c in selected.models.engine">
    <option value="">-- Model --</option>
</select>
```